# Images are not showing after WordPress Migration

Tags: wordpress, migration

I migrated one of my sites to WordPress from blogger but all of the post images are not showing up in WordPress site. I checked the uploads folder which has all post images and all folders have 755 permissions. But not showing images. I also Tried import external images plugin and cache images plugin.

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

Completely reinstalled Wordress and imported using Blogger Importer Extended plugin and now i am able to see all images, posts and pages. Problem solved.

Comment: Check the URL of images for where its trying to load image. Share the website URL.

Comment: Its not showing images for some post and showing blogspot uploaded images for other. My site Url is http://tricksladder.com. I tried cache images plugin which uploaded images to uplodes folder but some images can't be cached.

Comment: Kindly share the post with issue !

Comment: Now completely reinstalled wordpress and imported using Blogger Importer Extended plugin and now i am able to see all images, posts and pages. Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know problem is solved (y)